# Algebraic Integers in Cyclotomic fields

Tags: number-theory, minimal-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive 8th root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\alpha = \frac{1-\zeta}{2}$

(i) Determine the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

(ii) Is $\alpha^{-1}$ an algebraic integer?

I think I have part (i) sorted since I know $\zeta^{8} = 1$ so I have the minimal polynomial of $\zeta = x^4 +1$. So the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ should be $(1-2x)^4 +1$ ? Would love confirmation on that though!

I'm not sure about part (ii) though... Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For part (i), your work looks good to me! Beware, some people require minimal polynomials to be *monic*, in which case you can just expand out the expression you have and divide by the leading coefficient.

For (ii), I'll give you a hint first: what's the norm of $1 - \zeta$ for the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}$?

> Note that the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ is
>  $$m(x) = x^4 +1 = (x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^3)(x-\zeta^5)(x-\zeta^7).$$
>  Thus, we have
>  $$ \mathrm{Nm}(1-\zeta) = (1-\zeta)(1-\zeta^3)(1-\zeta^5)(1-\zeta^7) = m(1) = 2, $$
>  so that
>  $$ \frac{1-\zeta}{2} \cdot (1-\zeta^3)(1-\zeta^5)(1-\zeta^7) = 1. $$